# How to type __eq__ in generic Python class?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

When I define a type with generic type parameters (e.g. `K`/`V` for key and value of a mapping), I seemingly cannot write a suitable `isinstance` check for implementing `__eq__`:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from typing import TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")

class MyDictWrapper(MutableMapping[K, V]):

  def __init__(self):
    self.cache: OrderedDict[K, V] = OrderedDict()

  def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(other, MyDictWrapper):
      return NotImplemented
    return self.cache == other.cache  # Pyright error: Type of "cache" is partially unknown: Type of "cache" is "OrderedDict[Unknown, Unknown]
```

(This is on `pyright 1.1.309`, see [Pyright Playground repro](https://pyright-play.net/?pyrightVersion=1.1.349&pythonVersion=3.12&pythonPlatform=Linux&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAqiApgGoCGIAUKJFAMZgA2Tx9MSYKAzptrvgDyIACbEQxEQBEk7GuGiMWbDl24A6cgCN6fHHigBZAK4xtrQ%2BQTJ0VKgGkoAXkIkKIABQAie14CUVKTOrghklN6k-nb0TOTcvIZwMuwA6iBWoZ4mZloWGahoANr2ADRQpAC6fgBcdlBQYsBQAPrNqEgwrR7cxEzANVT19T196vTk9AAWxNVQwmIS0rIwxWWVwfPikskwHgGDDcRNrcQAjl0jwGVgMNMgs2BaAFYqflAAtAB8UFpgzLVDTBNFA3TDcVDcMwoejEDw3O5lRI7NIZcQDQH1CQwYwgFBQAByNwAkthWBBiCgYJIDpjiNjcVBLmMJtNnC54eJmVNiPUAMRQAAKcBASDQk3w4nA9xCPLATS8425XjBUAQlA45BYcCgxhQAGsQQB3FCzIihKByqAKlnEZVIXheTaLHaFACq%2BqNKDK7oNYGNFSAA).)

The alternative

```py
    if not isinstance(other, MyDictWrapper[K, V]):
```

also does not work, errors with:

```
Second argument to "isinstance" must be a class or tuple of classes
  Generic type with type arguments not allowed for instance or class
```

Is there a correct way to type this?

Comment: What is `LRUCache`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce (after replacing `LRUCache` with `MyDictWrapper`) with PyRight 1.1.349 and Python 3.12.

Comment: _What is LRUCache_ -- my bad, I meant `MyDictWrapper`. I did not replace all class names when minimising/generalising the example. I originally set out to write an LRU cache, and then encountered the general question of how to type wrappers of Python dicts.

Comment: @chepner I can reproduce it with the versions you mentioned, on the Pyright Playground. I added a repro link to the question.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume by `LRUCache` you mean `MyDictWrapper`.)

A [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) would be useful:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=7c263cb049b55da72e8cbce82c54743c), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAqiApgGoCGIANFAIIpw0DG5AzjAFCiRRNgA2-YkxhIwKVpmy58AeRAATYiGIKAIkhFdw0PoOGjxrAHTkARkyk48UALIBXGOaG3yCZOg4cA0lAC8hCQUIAAUAETeYQCUHKT%2BgQhklOGk0V5M-GyStnAaIgDqIG6JoQ5OZi7FqGgA2t40pAC6UQBcXlBQSsBQAPo9qEgwfSGsxPzAUVAAtAB8UABy4sRtHR2j48YsTAAWy1DySirqmjB1DY3xB8qqeTAhMRwdXb09xACOw%2BvANGAwuyAtKBgMwAKwMk1mUDMYAEK1WSG6KF%2BmFYqHY5BQTGIIV%2B-xoOVuhWKylaj1WHRUMHsIBQC1%2BAElsEIIMQUDBVO1VrjlPEWOwQgSTkT3MoavRGHQGI0fn8SZyKcQqTSoF9NuQdsR-AFuSA1RqOEA))</sub>

```py
class MyDictWrapper(MutableMapping[K, V]):

  ...

  def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(other, MyDictWrapper):
      return NotImplemented

    other = cast(MyDictWrapper[Any, Any], other)
    # Pyright => fine
    # mypy    => error: Redundant cast to "MyDictWrapper[Any, Any]"

    return self.cache == other.cache
```

The error happens because mypy interprets `MyDictWrapper` as `MyDictWrapper[Any, Any]` by default. To quote [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types):

> Using a generic class without specifying type parameters assumes [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) for each position.

Better yet, you can use a custom `TypeGuard`:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=66a23154e9efccff6b974493e7f1bc52), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwChHRIokBPXLUgc2zwEiAFS5oAasRAAaKAEFSHWaNxoA4gikATFuGgBjMABsjafTTr0B%2BQlADyILWnRaAIlnO62hk2YsMAOmIAI31rISgAWWQQ00jiXG4%2BZgBpKABeKBUJKQAKACIU-IBKRnEMrLFJEALxEuYnYFgsehgtDyQYAHcQBNUasGCAKwAuKEGhv2KoAFoAPkrVDW0AbUiOd3MAdV7E5xWFJXlFAF0TkcYoKHQUEFJseh56KlJ9NFyJ2XXNpB2%2B51KjH0RmI9Cs3w6fz2NWiVGCcT6PF4KxSsnEJ2KF0uUEasBgPCwnRguXoaCMwGm8ygADk6GgLlcrqTyQF9MR9AALen2RzONBuDootEnCoOJwuH65QFXXFwNAARzgJLJwFklC5IDGEymswWwTAxgZjKwTQoRHxrXa5m6u36HyQGsx2MZ1zQt3utKQAEk8KYIGhSEh%2BcwXTdUPdmcBWeyuRlMurnNHOWhGEA))</sub>

```py
def _is_dict_wrapper(obj: object) -> TypeGuard[MyDictWrapper[Any, Any]]:
  return isinstance(obj, MyDictWrapper)
```

```py
class MyDictWrapper(MutableMapping[K, V]):

  ...

  def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if not _is_dict_wrapper(other):  # mypy & Pyright => fine
      return NotImplemented

    return self.cache == other.cache
```

Comment: The cast should not be necessary, and the error message implies type narrowing has been applied successfully, since the error is not that an object of type `object` has no attribute `cache`, but that the type of `cache` isn't fully known.

Comment: @chepner Correct: Pyright just chose to be less lenient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **origin** attribute to check against the generic class without specifying type parameters.

```
if isinstance(other, MyDictWrapper) and other.__origin__ is MyDictWrapper:
        return self.cache == other.cache
    return NotImplemented
```

Comment: Should this help with the pyright type checking? My pyright does not accept it: `Cannot access member "__origin__" for type "object"`